# Is there a way to clean up a text file (get rid of similar words)? (Without using nested for loops)

Tags: pseudocode

I'm trying to think of the optimal way to clean up text in a file. So what I want to do is, given an input file, match words that are similar and replace them. So if apple and ApPle are in the file, ApPle would be replaced by apple.

Is there any way to do this without using two for loops like so:

```
for $word in @file
  for $word2 in @file
    if $word matches $word2
      replace $word2 with $word
    end
  end
end
```

I'm always hesitant to use nested for loops so I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant solution. Also, if you're wondering why it's pseudocode, it's because I haven't decided what to program this in yet. (For those who don't know @file is a list of words and $word is a non-whitespace string of characters).

Comment: Where does the regex come into play?

Comment: @user946850 replace "match" with whatever regex I decide to use. I'm not as concerned about how I want it to match as much as how I should iterate through the data.

Comment: Would it be some "find" or "replace" operation using a regular expression, executed on the two words in your example? That can be used as a non-injective hash function for sure :-)

Comment: @user946850 Yeah, I just wanted to do it as nonspecific as possible in pseudocode so all could reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work:

- Define a unique representation (a "hash function") for similar words. (If it's only difference in case, that's easy. If it's similar pronounciation, that's more difficult.)
- Read the file in one pass, maintain a "hash table" and print the word only if it's not yet in the hash table.

.

```
for $word in @file
  hash=hashfunction($word)
  if $hash not in §hashtable
    add $hash to §hashtable
    print $hash
  end
end
```

If your hash function is not injective, things get slightly more complicated.

Comment: Yes, this is much more elegant. I'm surprised I didn't think of hash!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what "similar" means to you, and when words should be replaced. Should the code determine this? Do you want to turn everything that's in uppercase into lowercase, or should the code use different criteria to do this?

In PHP, you could conceivably use (a combination of) these functions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php (case-insensitive replace)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php (convert a string to lowercase)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php (convert a string to uppercase)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php (see how similar string A is to string B)

If you can post more details about your intended use case, you'll probably get better answers :)

Comment: The similarity doesn't matter, it's the process that compares them that does. If you must know, it'll be a regex, but that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, in that case this is probably not what you were looking for, but for the pronunciation issue raised by @user946850, you could use something like PHP's metaphone or soundex (or the equivalent in other languages).